# Determine "Recommended" display resolution settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Got the code that gets a list of the monitors (using EnumDisplayDevices) along with getting all the settings (using EnumDisplaySettings) for each monitor working just fine.

However, when I right click my desktop and adjust the resolution one of the settings is tagged as being "Recommended." Also, interestingly, for that particular resolution, EnumDisplaySettings lists 5 settings (varying by frequency) available. 30, 29, 25, 24, and 23. And when I select the "recommended" setting it selects the frequency 29.

I want to know how it picked that one. What criteria is it using?

In the display setting code I've found (quite helpful BTW for adjusting your desktop for an online meeting) it has of course an error catching routine with multiple possible error results. But, somehow Windows knows which settings will work. If I could filter the list that would be great.

TIA

Comment: To be more specific, I'm hoping for another (possibly) Pinvoke method that returns information that would allow me to determine that at resolution W x H, that a frequency of X is more compatible with the hardware than Y.